# Operators for classes in C++

Tags: c++

I want to clear a priority vector class, which works like priority_queue but is vector based. I want to use [] operator for accessing an element of the vector, I did something but the program just keep crashing. Any suggestions?

```
     #include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<typeinfo>

using namespace std;

string first (string a, string b){
int siz = min(a.size(), b.size());
int place = 0;
while (a[place]==b[place] && place<siz){
    place++;
}
if (a[place]>b[place]){
    return b;
}
else if (a[place]<b[place]){
    return a;
}
}

template <class type>
class priority_vector{
public:
type check;
string check2;
vector <type> pv;
bool isString(){
if (typeid(type).name()==typeid(check2).name()){return true;}
else {return false;}
}
void push_in(type input){
if (isString()){
    if (pv.size()==0){
        pv.push_back(input);
    }
    else{
        vector <type> :: iterator vit;
        vit = pv.begin();
        while (first(*pv, input)==*pv){
            pv ++;
        }
        vit.insert(vit, input);
    }
}
else{
    if(pv.size()==0){
        pv.push_back(input);
    }
    else{
        vector <type> :: iterator vit;
        vit = pv.begin();
        while (*pv<input){
            pv++;
        }
        vit.insert(vit, input);
    }
}
}
type operator[](int a){
return pv[a];
}
};

int main(){
priority_vector <string> v_s;
int n;
cin>>n;
int in;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>n;
    v_s.push_in(n);
}
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<v_s[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My first suggestion would be to properly indent your code.

Comment: There is such a thing as a debugger. Step through the code yourself and find out how and where it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) container adaptor by default uses [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). What's more interesting is that `std::priority_queue` is actually one of the few standard classes designed to be *inherited*.

That means you can easily do something like

```
template<typename T>
class priority_vector : public std::priority_queue<T>
{
public:
    // Constructors...

    T const& operator[](size_t idx) const
    {
        return c[idx];
    }

    T& operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return c[idx];
    }
};
```